# Self managed secure fileserver

Tags: sftp, hosting, cpanel, webdav, sharing

I have 4 people who need to have a shared drive setup on a remote server. Confidentiality and encryption are important and hence most commercial web services (google drive, aws etc) are out of question.

I'm currently looking at the option of using WebDav (as cpanel's implementation Webdisk on a hosted account) for this.

Any thoughts if this is crazy - in terms of reliability or speed? If so what alternatives you may suggest? Ideally it needs to be natively configurable as a drive on Win10 + Mac, so sftp may be out.

Reqs: < 500 files, file sizes < 50mb, tiny traffic, 4 users, encryption

Comment: There's multiple ways to go about this, such as SSHFS, OpenVPN protected Samba shares, etc.  You could also go all out and set up your own VPN or SSH protected file server via [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/athome/), but that might be overkill for what you're needing

Comment: Can you connect to those using a native Win10 interface, e.g. mapping a drive w/o installing any applications? I also have a user with a Mac. Really after something very simple, reliable and secure. We do not need to support versioning or file locks or archiving.

Comment: The simplest setup would probably be SSHFS. Mac likely has an SSH client built-in, and Windows can either use [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH), [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html), or [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php).  For OpenVPN, the [OpenVPN client](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) is required to install, but it's the most user-friendly (point and click to connect).  The OpenVPN server would be best served running on a router, and allows mapping Samba shares in File Explorer.

Comment: Tu, regarding those technologies (it's been a while since I used PuTTY myself), do they have a "copy file path" location, so that this resolves in a link that other users quickly navigate to if the location is, e.g., emailed to them? It can be plain text.

Comment: You can copy and paste file links in all the above I mentioned.  With SSH (OpenSSH, PuTTY, WinSCP, SSHFS), copy and paste would be command line based, whereas WinSCP and SSHFS would be GUI based.  Connecting via OpenVPN and using a Samba share would allow GUI navigation, copy/paste, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits go to @JW0914, in the end we adopted NextCloud, which generally works reasonably well for our purposes. Its feature of having a local mirror of the remote server comes handy as we have many large media files it would be impossible to traverse efficiently without it. Synchronisation worked rather effortlessly on NC and almost with no delay after any file change was detected.

We were not able to fix link sharing to files on NextCloud for our team though, since one of our users is on Linux and the locations where the desktop client installs varies + there's an issue with back and forward slashes which we do not know how to resolve.